# How to write firebase function sending message after 5 minutes?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm writing firebase functions using pubsub and scheduler.
I want to publishMessage after 5 minutes later from timilimitScheduler function start.
But timelimitScheduler send message briefly. So cancelReservation function worked and reservation cancelled in 10 seconds...

```js
exports.timelimitScheduler = functions.firestore// eslint-disable-line
  .document('Reservation/{documentId}')// eslint-disable-line
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {// eslint-disable-line
    const newReservation = snapshot.data();// eslint-disable-line
    const userId = newReservation.userId;// eslint-disable-line
    const shopId = newReservation.shopId;// eslint-disable-line

    const topicName = 'reservation-cancellation';// eslint-disable-line
    const reservationId = context.params.documentId;// eslint-disable-line
    const data = JSON.stringify({ reservationId });// eslint-disable-line
    const pubSubClient = new PubSub();// eslint-disable-line

    const delaySeconds = 300;// eslint-disable-line
    const publishTime = new Date(Date.now() + delaySeconds * 1000);// eslint-disable-line
    console.log('Scheduled publish time:', publishTime);// eslint-disable-line    
      const message = {// eslint-disable-line
        data: Buffer.from(data),// eslint-disable-line
    attributes: {// eslint-disable-line
                scheduledTime: publishTime.getTime().toString(),// eslint-disable-line
            },// eslint-disable-line
      };// eslint-disable-line

      return pubSubClient// eslint-disable-line
  .topic(topicName)// eslint-disable-line
  .publishMessage(message)// eslint-disable-line
  .then((messageId) => {// eslint-disable-line
    console.log(`Message ${messageId} published at ${publishTime}`);// eslint-disable-line
    return null;// eslint-disable-line
  })// eslint-disable-line
  .catch((error) => {// eslint-disable-line
    console.error(`Error publishing message: ${error}`);// eslint-disable-line
    throw error;// eslint-disable-line
  });// eslint-disable-line
  });// eslint-disable-line
```

```js
exports.cancelReservation = functions.pubsub.topic('reservation-cancellation')// eslint-disable-line
    .onPublish((message) => {// eslint-disable-line
        const reservationId = message.json.reservationId;// eslint-disable-line
        const scheduledTime = parseInt(message.attributes.scheduledTime, 10);// eslint-disable-line
        const delaySeconds = Math.floor((Date.now() - scheduledTime) / 1000);// eslint-disable-line
        console.log(`Canceling reservation ${reservationId} (delayed by ${delaySeconds} seconds)`);// eslint-disable-line
        return admin.firestore().collection('Reservation').doc(reservationId).get()// eslint-disable-line
            .then((reservationDoc) => {// eslint-disable-line
                const reservation = reservationDoc.data();// eslint-disable-line
                if (reservation.state !== '예약접수') {// eslint-disable-line
                    return;// eslint-disable-line
                }// eslint-disable-line
                return admin.firestore().collection('Reservation').doc(reservationId).update({// eslint-disable-line
                    state: '예약취소',// eslint-disable-line
                });// eslint-disable-line
            })// eslint-disable-line
            .catch((error) => {// eslint-disable-line
                console.error(`Error canceling reservation: ${error}`);// eslint-disable-line
                throw error;// eslint-disable-line
            });// eslint-disable-line
    });// eslint-disable-line
```

Comment: Firebase Functions are not meant to make scheduled operations. Use scheduler to trigger `timelimiSheduler` and after 5 min same scheduler should trigger function to send a message. Make two API calls with 5 min gap instead of one.

Comment: Oh, and use server time. XD Or you have everything not synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

`Cloud Tasks` work great for this. In `Firebase` you can [Enqueue functions with Cloud Tasks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions) which essentially allows you to programmatically queue a task *to start at a specified time*. The key property for that is `scheduleTime` which is "time from now" that the function will start.

Comment: How to do that? I'm very struggling solving issue using your solution. But.. so hard

Comment: Here's an example of a module you can use to create a cloud task. A cloud task will run a `Cloud Function` in x-seconds from now. --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75425962/gcp-cloud-function-queue/75427073#75427073 --- You basically give it some data (`body`) and then it will contact your created `Cloud Task` which you must create in the GCP Console under `Tasks`. This example module could be called `createCloudTask.ts` (or .js). Then you can execute it from inside your code above where necessary. Your `publishMessage` function should be a separate cloud function that accepts `message`.